# Making turtle objects draw next to each other instead of on top of each other

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am having an issue where instead of my turtle objects drawing a car length next to each other, they are drawing on top of each other. I've tried just about every variation of a loop I could think of, but just can not figure it out despite it probably being something so simple. In addition to this, I haven't been able to figure out how to get the name of the car a user enters to appear above their respective car.
Here is what it is supposed to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rubG3.png

```
import turtle
import random
turtle.setup(575,575)
pen = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.bgcolor("white")
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(2)
pen.hideturtle()

colorCar = []
carName = []

# ask user how many cars
carNum = int(turtle.numinput("cars", "Enter how many cars you have: ", 1, 1, 10))

# respective values (add more variables if needed for sizing)
widthPadding = turtle.window_width()/carNum 
width= widthPadding * .8
padding = widthPadding * .1
length = width * 2

# controlls how long horizontally
carWidth = width * 0.5
wheelWidth = carWidth * .1
# controls how long vertically
carLength = width * 0.2

for row in range(carNum):
    x = - turtle.window_width()/2 + carWidth
    y = - turtle.window_height()/2 + padding + row * widthPadding


# ask user for color of car
for i in range(carNum):
    color = turtle.textinput("car color", f"Enter Color of Car {i +1}").lower().strip() 
    colorCar.append(color)
    # ask for car name
    name = turtle.textinput("car name", f"Enter Name of Car {i +1}").lower().strip()
    carName.append(name)


    for row in range(carNum):
        pen.up()
        pen.setpos(x + (width - length)/2 + padding, y)
        pen.down()

        #draw cars
        pen.color("black")
        pen.pensize(4)
        pen.fillcolor(color)
        pen.begin_fill()
        for i in range(4):
            if i%2== 0:
                pen.forward(carWidth)
            else:
                pen.forward(carLength)
            pen.left(90)
        pen.end_fill()

        # write name above car
        turtle.write(name)


turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a mess.  You need to use better variable names.  It's not clear what various "width", "length" and "padding" variables do.  In fact, this is where comments are really needed, not comments like `# ask for car name` just before you obviously ask for the car name.

Below I've reworked your code to address your two stated issues: the cars line up horizontally rather than atop each other; the names of the cars appear above the cars:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(575, 575)

# ask user how many cars
carNum = int(screen.numinput("cars", "Enter how many cars you have: ", 1, 1, 10))

# respective values (add more variables if needed for sizing)
widthPadding = screen.window_width() / carNum
width = widthPadding * 0.8
padding = widthPadding * 0.1
length = width * 2

# controls how long horizontally
bodyWidth = width / 2

# controls how long vertically
bodyHeight = width * 0.2

carColors = []
carNames = []

for i in range(1, carNum + 1):
    # ask user for color of car
    color = screen.textinput("car color", f"Enter Color of Car {i}").lower().strip()
    carColors.append(color)

    # ask for car name
    name = screen.textinput("car name", f"Enter Name of Car {i}").lower().strip()
    carNames.append(name)

# draw cars
turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.pensize(4)

for car in range(carNum):
    x = bodyWidth - screen.window_width()/2 + car * widthPadding
    y = padding - screen.window_height()/2

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(x + (width - length)/2 + padding, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.fillcolor(carColors[car])
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for side in range(4):
        if side % 2 == 0:
            turtle.forward(bodyWidth)
        else:
            turtle.forward(bodyHeight)

        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()

    # write name above car
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 3*bodyHeight/2)
    turtle.write(carNames[car])

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]